# How to configure a connection pool Apache Tomcat-> PostgreSQL-> Persistence Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jpa, pool

I have a Java Web project with Java8 using Postgresql9.3 on an Apache Tomcat7 Server. I am using Persistence for the connection to the database but I can not configure the Apache Tomcat Connection Pool to manage the traffic of the App with the Database.

So far I have searched in different forums and what I have found is in the context.xhtml file of Apache tomcat add these lines:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ead" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="postgres" password="postgres" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/SIGENU_EaD"/>
```

In the web.xml file of the web project add these lines:

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/ead</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>org.postgresql.Driver</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My question is how to add this configuration to the persistence.xml file so that when using the JpaControllers generated by Persistence, use the Apache Tomcat Pool instead of a direct connection.

The current persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dist_educ_finalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entity.EstadoCivil</class>
        <class>entity.ProcedenciaEscolar</class>
        <class>entity.Disciplina</class>
        <class>entity.Planestudio</class>
        <class>entity.FuenteIngreso</class>
        <class>entity.TipoAsignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Especialidad</class>
        <class>entity.MatriculaEstudianteAsignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Organismo</class>
        <class>entity.Asignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Huerfano</class>
        <class>entity.Tutor</class>
        <class>entity.ColorPiel</class>
        <class>entity.GradoMilitar</class>
        <class>entity.EspecialidadMilitar</class>
        <class>entity.Authorities</class>
        <class>entity.Ocupacion</class>
        <class>entity.Carreranacional</class>
        <class>entity.Minusvalia</class>
        <class>entity.Estudiante</class>
        <class>entity.Sexo</class>
        <class>entity.NivelEscolar</class>
        <class>entity.Users</class>
        <class>entity.Universidad</class>
        <class>entity.OrganizacionPolitica</class>
        <class>entity.OrganizacionPopular</class>
        <class>entity.Municipio</class>
        <class>entity.TipoEvaluacion</class>
        <class>entity.Examen</class>
        <class>entity.Matricula</class>
        <class>entity.MatriculaEstudianteAsignaturaExamen</class>
        <class>entity.Pais</class>
        <class>entity.Centrotrabajo</class>
        <class>entity.EstadoEstudiante</class>
        <class>entity.Curso</class>
        <class>entity.Provincia</class>
        <class>entity.Ong</class>
        <class>entity.Sindicato</class>
        <class>entity.Area</class>
        <class>entity.Carrera</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SIGENU_EaD"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: By the way, check the [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) site: “PostgreSQL 9.3 is now end-of-life and will no longer receive any bug or security fixes. We urge users to start planning an upgrade to a later version of PostgreSQL as soon as possible.”

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but that does not depend on me. The system must adapt to an environment already defined some years ago and I am not the owner of the original software. My software is a module to that other software and will be installed on the same server with the same environment. I have to use the same environment to avoid generating conflicts, this software is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="dist_educ_finalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/ead</non-jta-data-source>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

Comment: I solved the problem, the idea you gave me worked well. But besides that, I had a badly written word among the codes. In the context.xml file the word "resources" is misspelled, it was "resource" what had to be written. Due to that when running the server appeared a series of errors in the log, could not find the tags "name", "auth" and etc. But I already solved it, Thanks for the help.